# How to resolve duplicate class exception caused by com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition

While setting up the Text Recognizer for MLKit on Android for a react-native project (following this tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text?authuser=0) I face an exception when launching the application with the `react-native run-android` command in my terminal.

It states I have duplicate classes and I tracked it down to when I add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.0'` to the app/build.gradle

Has anyone faced this before and resolved it? If I remove that line and change line 134 of android/app/build Gradle back to 'general' from 'mlkit' I can run my react-native-camera module but I cannot interface with the MLKit text recognizer.

Exception:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzbm found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzck found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzcl found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzcm found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzjx found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzjy found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzjz found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzka found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzkb found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzkc found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzkd found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzke found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzkg found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzl found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your `app/build.gradle`

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue trying to use `com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1` - my `app/build.gradle` is https://gist.github.com/mhuebert/5b3b18069ca59b529002c52ff8a2b939

Comment: did anyone found the solution?